# How to load and play video from a web service

Tags: c#, media

I've been doing a project like a cinema online. I use windows form as my client, and I have a web service. When a user is authorized from server, he/she can watch a video.

I really don't know how to transfer a video from webservice to client ? Are there any good tips or tutorials ?
Thanks first :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Avoid things traditionally called "web services" in .NET (such as .asmx web services and WCF SOAP web services) for this type of task. You don't want to send a gigantic blob of Base64 encoded video down to the client.

There are server products specifically designed for this kinda thing like [Windows Media Services](http://www.microsoft.com/windows/windowsmedia/forpros/server/server.aspx) or [IIS Smooth Streaming](http://www.iis.net/download/SmoothStreaming).

Basically you'll want to have your videos encoded and ready to go on the server and then perhaps use a web service to provide the authenticated client with a direct link to those streams.